# QJsonDocument::toJson() incorrect double precision

Tags: c++, json, qt, double, qjson

In my project I read from a json file with `QJsonDocument::fromJson()`. This works great, however when I try to write the `QJsonDocument` back to file with `toJson()` some of the doubles have messed up precision.

For example, calling `toJson()` on a document with a `QJsonValue` with a double value of `0.15` will save to file as `0.14999999999999999`. I do not want this.

This is because the Qt source file `qjsonwriter.cpp at line 126 (Qt 5.6.2)` reads:

```
json += QByteArray::number(d, 'g', std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 2); // ::digits10 is 15
```

That +2 at the end there is messing me up. If this same call to `QByteArray::number()` instead has a precision of 15 (instead of 17), the result is exactly as I need... `0.15`.

I understand how the format of floating point precision causes the double to be limited in what it can represent. But if I limit the precision to 15 instead of 17, this has the effect of matching the input double precision, which I want.

How can I get around this?

Obviously... I could write my own Json parser, but that's last resort. And obviously I could edit the Qt source code, however my software is already deployed with the Qt5Core.dll included in everyone's install directory, and my updater is not designed to update any dll's. So I cannot edit the Qt source code.

Fingers crossed someone has a magic fix for this :)

Comment: Is it possible to save numbers as hex float? (`%a`, see the table [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) for more explanation)

Comment: I do not have control over what QJsonDocument does after I call toJson(). If I did, I could surely save it in whatever format I want. At least, thats what im trying to confirm here.

Comment: Isn't `'g'` the format string?

Comment: Correct, but as I stated, I do not have control over the Qt source. That line of code is not mine. I showed it because it is the crux of the issue. Precision of 17 is hard coded.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51280431/14065

Comment: @MartinYork No. As I stated twice now, I dont have control over how QJson write the double to file.

Comment: @mrg95 The linked example shows you how to avoid using double in the first place. But you would have to re-write so you are using a different serialization library.

Comment: My question was never how to write the double, it was how to get QJson to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this has the effect of matching the input double precision, which I want.

This request doesn't make much sense. A double doesn't carry any information about its precision - it only carries a value. 0.15, 0.1500 and 0.14999999999999999 are the exact same double value, and the JSON writer has no way to know how it was read from the file in first place (*if* it was read from a file at all).

In general you cannot ask for maximum 15 digits of precision as you propose, as, depending from the particular value, up to 17 are required for a precise double->text->double roundtrip, so you would write incorrectly rounded values. What some JSON writers do however is to write numbers with *the minimum number of decimals required to read the same double back*. This is far from trivial to do numerically correctly unless you do - as many do - a loop from 15 to 17, write the number with such precision, parse it back and see if it comes back as the exact same double value. While this generates "nicer" (and smaller) output, it's more work and slows down the JSON write, so that's why probably Qt doesn't do this.

Still, you can write your own JSON write code and have this feature, for a simple recursive implementation I expect ~15 lines of code.

That being said, again, if you want to precisely match your input this won't save you - as it's simply impossible.

Comment: To rephrase, the json file I'm loading has been generated from other software that writes doubles with a lower precision than 17. I need control over how QJson write doubles so it matches what the output would be from the other software.

My solution was to write my own parser.

Comment: If you write all the values with precision 15 you are going to lose precision, as it's not enough for many values. I'm almost sure that, if that JSON comes from any of the "mainstream" JSON writers, it writes down numbers with the minimum precision to represent the value exactly, not fixed 15. Also, as I said above, from a machine standpoint it makes no difference if you write down the number with more precision than needed - it's effectively the same number. Finally, a *parser* is some code that converts textual representation to machine representation, while what you wrote is the opposite.

Comment: How does one determine what the "exact" value is then? Clearly, in my situation, the number I was trying to write was "exactly" 0.14999999999999999. The value changes depending on the precision I give it. So how does one determine what the "true" value is supposed to be in order to compare it?

Comment: @mrg95: the "true" value is what the 8 bytes of the double contain; OTOH, there are **many** *decimal representations* that will yield exactly the same double value when parsed. 0.14999999999999999, 0.15, 0.150, 0.14999999999999999445 all parse back to the same value. What you want to output is a matter of preference. Do you want to optimize speed? Just write with 17 decimals, it'll always be right. For human readability? Use the loop I said above - try `%0.15g`, if it parses back as the same `double` you are ok; otherwise try `%0.16g`, otherwise `%0.17g`.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're saying now. Sorry I didn't catch that earlier. I'll implement this into my pars.... um.... writer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this as well.  Rather than replace an entire Qt JSON implementation with a third party library (or roll my own!), however, I *kludged* a solution...

My full code base related to this is too extensive and elaborate to post and explain here.  But the gist of the solution to this point is simple enough.

First, I use a QVariantMap (or QVariantHash) to collect my data, and then convert that to json via the built-in `QJsonObject::fromVariantMap` or `QJsonDocument::fromVariant` functions.  To control the serialization, I define a class called `DataFormatOptions` which has a `decimalPrecision` member (and sets up easy expansion to other such formatting options..) and then I call a function called `toMagicVar` to create "magic variants" for my data structure to be converted to json bytes.  To control for the number format / precision `toMagicVar` converts doubles and floats to strings that are in the desired format, and surrounds the string value with some "magic bytes".  The way my actual code is written, one can easily do this on any "level" of the map/hash I'm building / formatting via recursive processing, but I've omitted those details...

```
const QString NO_QUOTE( "__NO_QUOT__" );

QVariant toMagicVar( const QVariant &var, const DataFormatOptions &opt )
{
...
    const QVariant::Type type( var.type() );
    const QMetaType::Type metaType( (QMetaType::Type)type );
... 
    if( opt.decimalPrecision != DataFormatOptions::DEFAULT_PRECISION
        && (type == QVariant::Type::Double || metaType == QMetaType::Float) )
    {
            static const char FORMAT( 'f' );
            static const QRegExp trailingPointAndZeros( "\\.?0+$" );
            QString formatted( QString::number(
                var.toDouble(), FORMAT, opt.decimalPrecision ) );
            formatted.remove( trailingPointAndZeros );
            return QVariant( QString( NO_QUOTE + formatted + NO_QUOTE ) );
    }
... 
}
```

Note that I trim off any extraneous digits via `formatted.remove`.  If you want the data to always include exactly X digits after the decimal point, you may opt to skip that step.  (Or you might want to control that via `DataFormatOptions`?)

Once I have the json bytes I'm going to send across the network as a `QByteArray`, I remove the magic bytes so my numbers represented as quoted strings become numbers again in the json.

```
// This is where any "magic residue" is removed, or otherwise manipulated,
// to produce the desired final json bytes...
void scrubMagicBytes( QByteArray &bytes )
{
    static const QByteArray EMPTY, QUOTE( "\"" ),
        NO_QUOTE_PREFIX( QUOTE + NO_QUOTE.toLocal8Bit() ),
        NO_QUOTE_SUFFIX( NO_QUOTE.toLocal8Bit() + QUOTE );
    bytes.replace( NO_QUOTE_PREFIX, EMPTY );
    bytes.replace( NO_QUOTE_SUFFIX, EMPTY );
}
```